# How to debug a form submit with xdebug using netbeans?

Tags: php, forms, netbeans, submit, xdebug

I want to debug a form submit using netbeans but cannot find the option to do so, I know in eclipse there's an option called debug all pages.

So when you submit the form the next page loaded (the one who receives post parameters) automatically starts within the current xdebug session, so you're able to trace the code that manages the post values.

I wanted to know if there's such an option or a way to do this in netbeans, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some possibilities.

A) Depending on your version of Netbeans:
Tools->Options->PHP->General
check "Stop at First Line"

Tools->Options->PHP->Debugging
check "Stop at First Line"

B) Make sure you add a breakpoint in the page that receives the post parameters, otherwise it will just load without stopping.

Be Well,
Joe

Comment: the thing is to have a breakpoint on the page that receives de the post parameters, otherwise it does not continuate the debugging flow. thanks!